# Only able to print entry of an array at most twice

Tags: c++, arrays, crash, cout

When I run the executable containing a function with the following code from the command line *result[1]* is only printed twice before the program crashes (" *.exe has stopped working ") even though blocklength is set to 25.

When I run the exact same executable with a double click the program crashes without printing anything. (but it runs until right before the for loop)

*result* is an array of type *double* and length *blocklength*, it is passed to the function as an argument.

```
for (int i = 0; i < blocklength; i++) {
    cout << result[1] << endl;
}
```

When I used the GNU Project Debugger (GDB) to go through the program step by step it printed out *result[1]* 25 times and did not crash.

Obviously the original for loop did more than just print the same value over and over, but I narrowed the problem down to this and am now totally stuck and confused.

I would really appreciate any help or inputs.

Here's the full code, *result* is defined in the main function as double* result = new double[blocklength] and immediately passed to the function:

```
void entropy(char* input, int l_input, double* result, int blocklength, char order)
{
    int l_counter = pow(order, blocklength);
    int* counter = new int[l_counter];
    double prob = 0;
    int max_counter = 1;
    int* temp = new int[l_input];

    for (int i = 0; i < l_input; i++) {
        temp[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int s = 1; s <= blocklength; s++)
    {
        max_counter *= order;

        // reset counter
        for (int i = 0; i < max_counter; i++) {
            counter[i] = 0;
        }

        // init result
        result[s] = 0;


        for (int b = 0; b < l_input + 1 - s; b++) {
            temp[b] = order * temp[b] + input[b - 1 + s];
            counter[temp[b]]++;
        }

        for (int b = 0; b < max_counter; b++) {
            prob =  counter[b] / (double)(l_input - s + 1);
            if (prob != 0)
            {
                result[s - 1] = result[s - 1] + fabs(prob * log(prob));
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Block " << s << " okay" << std::endl;
    }

    cout << "sum done" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < blocklength; i++)
    {
        cout << result[1] << endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Entroyp done!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You have to provide more code, from the code here probably noone will be able to deduct what went wrong. As far as I can see nothing is wrong with the 3 lines you provided, but I would suspect that you somewhere change the adress of the array instead of changing the value of it's elements.

Comment: blocklength is a char. Is that correct?

Comment: yes blocklength is a char, is this a problem?

Comment: Your usage of `blocklength` is that of an int, not a char. You use it in integer calcs, iterating over an array. Why is it even a char? Besides that, it's a `signed char` so it ranges from -128 to 127 (if your array length goes beyond 127 that's a problem).

Comment: I changed it to an int, still the same problem

Comment: `result[s]` and `cout << result[1] << endl;` are potential seg faults. `s` is a loop variable and starts with value 1, instead of 0, so there will be one invalid access. Then printing `result[1]` will result in another invalid access if blocklength == 1.

Comment: well, this is embarassing... it works!! but still: `blocklength` is equal to 25, why is `result[1]` an invalid access??

Comment: @bilsim As I said, it would be an invalid access if `blocklength` were equal to 1. If it's 25 then it's valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things that seem wrong with your code.
result[s] is not read/written after it's initialised.

```
result[s] = 0;
```

Instead result[s-1] is accessed.

```
result[s - 1] = result[s - 1] + fabs(prob * log(prob));
```

This means that result[0] will never be set to 0. This also means that `result[blocklength] = 0` will be assigned but never used.

If you have a line like `int* result = new int[blocklength];` in your code, then you access a value that isn't in your array at all. A valid index is between 0 and arrayLenght-1.

Or more general:
If your input is wrong your programm blows up. You have to ensure that no value beyond an arrays capacity is accessed, this should be done in the line/loop in which it is accessed, not somewhere else.

In this case you have to ensure that results capacity is atleast blocklength+1.